# how to convert a string in json format to normal string format in python

Tags: python, json, string

i'm receiving a string in json format. It is str format, like this:

```
'{"name":"Jason", "age":"10"}'
```

I want to transform it in a "normal" string, exactly like this:

```
Jason 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json) module to do this:

```
import json

data = json.loads(json_str)
print(data['name'], data['age'])
```